# ESLint doesn't lint ALL errors in command-line

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, eslint

I'm using eslint in my project, `.eslintrc` looks like:

```
// http://eslint.org/docs/rules
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "strict": 0,
    "quotes": [2, "single"],
    "indent": [2, 4, {SwitchCase: 1}],
    "semi": [2, "always"],
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 1,
    "no-unused-expressions": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 2,
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 0,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 1,
    "new-cap": 0,
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 0,
    "yoda": 0,
    "no-empty": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "camelcase": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "expect": true,
    "should": true,
    "FB": true,
    "gapi": true,
    "google": true,
    "customGoogleUtils": true,
    "encodeURIComonent": true,
    "decodeURIComonent": true
  }
}
```

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and with necessary plugins it lints code successfully:

[image]

However **when I'm running `eslint ./src` in command-line it doesn't show any errors!**. Even if I point it to specific file with errors in folder `eslint ./src/path/to/file/with/errors`.

I'm using the latest versions in `node_modules`:

- `"babel-eslint": "^5.0.0"`
- `"eslint": "^2.4.0"`
- `"eslint-plugin-react": "^4.2.3"`

**UPDATE**

The project folder structure is as follows (I'm linting only `/src` fodler):

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: You may want to check where `eslint` is invoked from (somewhere in your `PATH`) and that it is up to date. (`which eslint` and `eslint --version`)

Comment: can you add the file system of you project?

Comment: @BertrandMarron `eslint --versionbash: eslint: command not found` but `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --version v2.4.0`

Comment: @Zamboney updated the question

Comment: Interesting fact is that when using airbnb-config-eslint it throws a lot of errors. Though airbnb's config doesn't suit me, I want to extend it.

Comment: try to `eslint ./src/*.js` from the root of the folder you post here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a problem - lint errors were present in `.jsx` files and `eslint ./src` validated only `.js` by default.

In order to fix I've changed the cli command as follows - `eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx ./src`.

Comment: isn't there a better way? like doing it in the .eslintrc file?